How are "stock dividends" treated in total return swaps?
To be clear, I'm asking about the corporate action that dilutes the share base by awarding stocks to shareholders NOT the corporate action that awards cash.
As best I can tell, these are essentially mini stock splits with maybe some different tax implications (according to a couple of sources, but tbh I don't see it). That investopedia page in particular seems very fishy.
From the point of view of pricing TRS, how should we adjust the expected coupon to reflect the issuance? For stock splits, there is essentially no effect as we just use an adjustment factor on the final price when measuring performance over the coupon period. For stock dividends... I'm wondering if there is exceptional treatment? I've been trying to find ISDA documentation that would explain it, but e.g. I can't even find mentions of plain stock splits in the 2011 Equity Derivatives Definitions.

I dont know about taxes or ISDA templates, but from cash equities standpoint, one subtle, but important operational difference is that in a split / reverse split you just have more / fewer shares and can sell them right away if you want to. Sometimes you get some cash flow for fractional shares. In contrast, with a stock dividend, the new shares get accrued, but not actually delivered for some days, and can't be sold. I would avoid a position where I sell a TRS hedged with cash underlying, the counterparty suddenly decides to unwind the TRS, while I can't fully unwind the cash hedge because some of it is in the "accrued" state - rather wait until the accrued shares can be sold, then pass on the proceeds.

Great insight, thank you.

The investopedia page you linked mentions "holding period" which sounds like what I described, but I haven't heard this term.
